# Debugging -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have done some changes to my project and now I am getting above message when running the app and don't how how to debug it.
I have read *[here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Jun/msg00015.html)* that I have to put a break point in `-[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]` and set a condition as well.

But, how do I set the condition they mentioned? (Stop only when value is nil) I am on Xcode4 and only get this window when trying to set a breakpoint.

Currently it stops at every  `-[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]` which is not very helpful since it will stop even in correct calls and Apple's internal calls as well (too many!)

[image]

Comment: Let the App crash when it attempts to insert nil.If debugger console doesn't help.. go to ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/YourApp.crash ( find latest crash) and figure out from stack trace which part of code is causing it ( from Thread that crashed )

Comment: Mac app won't crash... it is simply not behaving as is should be.

Comment: @MacDev As the OP mentioned, he's getting an exception, not a crash. Also, catching these problems and showing the situation in the debugger is the IDE's job. Knowing how to do this means the difference between a beginner taking hours or days to find a problem and a pro spotting it in minutes or seconds. You should *definitely* learn how to use the debugger effectively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove that breakpoint and add an Exception breakpoint. This will stop on any exception (like attempting to insert nil into a dictionary). It's good practice to leave this breakpoint on for all debugging sessions, that way even intermittent exceptions (those hard-to-find problems) will be caught in the debugger the moment they happen.

To add an Exception breakpoint, click the Add (+) button at the bottom of the breakpoints list and click Add Exception Breakpoint. Leave it configured as-is.

Answer (score 0):

if you have reduced it to a call site, you can simply write:

```
assert(object);
[dictionary setObject:object forKey:key];
```