# good methods to debug iOS exception

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to debug my exception at my app,i have read

[Debugging -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752070/debugging-nscfdictionary-setobjectforkey-attempt-to-insert-nil-value)  add so on,but these methods is happen at i am running my app,so i can use  add an Exception breakpoint, click the Add (+) button at the bottom of the breakpoints list and click Add Exception Breakpoint ,and use gcc command line。but my  question is if user give me a crash report,the bug not easy happen,how to solve it ,for example:

```
  Application received signal SIGSEGV
  (null)
 (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x3120e2bb  + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x38f2b97f objc_exception_throw + 30
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3120e1c5  + 0
3   myshine                             0x001f9f51 myshine + 1503057
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x393a9e8b _sigtramp + 34
5   myshine                             0x000ac985 myshine + 137605
6   myshine                             0x000ac35d myshine + 136029
7   CoreFoundation                      0x311ab7cf  + 74
8   CoreFoundation                      0x311b1623  + 74
9   CoreFoundation                      0x311ab507  + 326
10  CFNetwork                           0x30f0fa8b  + 98
11  CFNetwork                           0x30f0ec71  + 36
12  CFNetwork                           0x30f11365  + 44
13  CFNetwork                           0x30f110f9  + 88
14  CFNetwork                           0x30f114ff  + 34
15  CFNetwork                           0x30ed0ce1  + 324
16  CFNetwork                           0x30ed1661  + 156
17  CFNetwork                           0x30f0ec71  + 36
18  CFNetwork                           0x30f11365  + 44
19  CoreFoundation                      0x311e3683  + 14
20  CoreFoundation                      0x311e2ee9  + 212
21  CoreFoundation                      0x311e1cb7  + 646
22  CoreFoundation                      0x31154ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
23  CoreFoundation                      0x311b39bb CFRunLoopRun + 98
24  myshine                             0x000b20ef myshine + 159983
25  Foundation                          0x31b24e85  + 972
26  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x39382311  + 308
27  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x393821d8 thread_start + 8
```

)

and

```
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 121 beyond bounds [0 .. 23]

 (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x311963ff  + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x38e87963 objc_exception_throw + 30
2   CoreFoundation                      0x310e1ef9  + 164
3   myshine                             0x001720b1 myshine + 1372337
4   UIKit                               0x33090087  + 70
5   UIKit                               0x3309003b  + 30
6   UIKit                               0x33090015  + 44
7   UIKit                               0x3308f8cb  + 502
8   UIKit                               0x3308fdb9  + 488
9   UIKit                               0x32fb85f9  + 524
10  UIKit                               0x32fa58e1  + 380
11  UIKit                               0x32fa51ef  + 6198
12  GraphicsServices                    0x34cbc5f7  + 590
13  GraphicsServices                    0x34cbc227  + 34
14  CoreFoundation                      0x3116b3e7  + 34
15  CoreFoundation                      0x3116b38b  + 138
16  CoreFoundation                      0x3116a20f  + 1382
17  CoreFoundation                      0x310dd23d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
18  CoreFoundation                      0x310dd0c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
19  GraphicsServices                    0x34cbb33b GSEventRunModal + 74
20  UIKit                               0x32ff92b9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
21  myshine                             0x00026ec7 myshine + 16071
22  myshine                             0x00025660 myshine + 9824
 )
```

through i know NSArray beyond bounds,but my app  have many many NSArray,and they are user report,can you give me some easy methods to find the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question what I understood is you want the method which has produced the crash in your app. May be this can help you [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports).

Comment: your answer is my need,but i have another question how to code generate crash report as http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs#   ,my code generate crash report not as the same as device generate,is it also can Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports?

Comment: @pengwang there're free solutions like https://www.crittercism.com if you want to get symbolicated crash reports automatically (not exactly the files that you'd have at ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter). If you want more control doing it manually, try using `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` and `callStackSymbols` of `NSException`.